# endpoint /beta/reports/getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail: is the report still generated in 48 hours?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm using MS Graph API endpoint `/beta/reports/getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail` on a daily basis. According to [this doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/activity-reports/activity-reports?view=o365-worldwide) it is expected that activity data is not available before 48 hours, thus I'm always using the `date` parameter with a value corresponding to "3 days ago".

However, when trying to retrieve activity data today for three different tenants, it appears that no activity data is available starting from november 13. That is, latest data available is from november 12 (confirmed by property `reportRefreshDate` of each user object, which is "2022-11-12" at best, when I query the report with parameter `period='D7'`), thus meaning **latest report data has been generated 5 days ago**

Plus, in the past few days, I got some `HTTP 504 / gateway timeout` errors when retrieving reports paginated data, not sure if this is related though.

**Is there currently an issue with user activity reports generation?**

**EDIT** a greater than 48 hours delay happened again between 10 and 17 april 2023, and is happening right how (may 2nd 2023) with `reportRefreshDate` having value `'2023-04-27'`). Is there any way to improve this service reliability, or to retrieve more up-to-date activity data?

**EDIT** 2023-05-03 looks solved by Microsoft ️

Comment: We did try this at our end, and we can see the report is available till 16-11-2022. We confirmed it with Report Refresh Date. Which means activity data is available before 48 hours.

Comment: Also added the issue on [Microsoft Q&A platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1275044/graph-api-teams-user-activity-report-refreshed-mor)

Comment: We will check this internally and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

This was likely an issue on MS Graph API side, which appears to be solved now.

This morning, when running the same query with parameter `period='D7'` I now get activity data statistics for two days ago